# What is the difference between the following definitions of Vector Functions and Parametric Curves?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, vectors, parametric, plane-curves

The definitions seem exactly the same to me. We have **a**(*t*) to be a vector function and **x**(*t*) to be a parametric curve where the tip of the position vector traces out a curve in an $n$-dimensional space as the input varies throughout it's domain values of *t*.

**Vector Functions**:

Vector functions are given by **a**: *I* $\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ with the domain *I*, an interval of $\mathbb{R}$, and the range being a subset of two or three dimensional space. For example, with $n = 3$, with respect to the ﬁxed orthonormal basis ${\bf{e}}_1$, ${\bf{e}}_2$ and ${\bf{e}}_3$. The vector ${\bf{a}}(t)$ can be written as $${\bf{a}}(t)=a_1(t){\bf{e}}_1 + a_2(t){\bf{e}}_2 + a_3(t){\bf{e}}_3.$$

**Parametric Curves**:

A parametric curve is a function **x** : *I* →$\mathbb{R}^n$, **x** : *t* $\mapsto$ **x**(*t*) where *I* is an interval. We will consider $n = 2$ (two-dimesional parametric curves, or plane curves) and $n = 3$ (three-dimensional parametric curves, space curves). Some deﬁnitions further require the function **x** to be diﬀerentiable. As the parameter *t* varies in the interval *I*, the point with position vector **x**(*t*) traces out a curve.

Comment: What's "an interval of $\mathbb R^n$"?

Comment: That was an error. I've corrected it to $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks.

Comment: In which case it looks the same to me, except that curves usually have some amount of smoothness to them. Maps $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ (which is what I previously thought you called vector functions) are of course not the same